# Kubectl Error : Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection

Tags: kubectl

I have downloaded kubectl on windows 10 pro and have set the environment variable also and now i am trying to check the version of it by running the command as shown below.

```
C:\bin>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
```

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

Want to know the reason for the failure and how will it impact my further work?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your environment?Did you use Minikube/ kubeadm to build the cluster? VMs build on Virtual Box or Hyper-V? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like you do not have a .kube/config file present in the default dir